# No need to use Alternatives to construct alternative string patterns?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I am trying to match a list of strings with a pattern, in which there are several possibilities for the characters to be matched. To me, the following looks the most natural way:

```
 StringMatchQ[{"12", "23", "34", "45"}, ___ ~~ Alternatives @@ {"1", "4"} ~~ ___]
```

what returns as expected:

> {True, False, True, True}

However, I've found out the following does work too (and it's faster when the list is very large):

```
StringMatchQ[{"12", "23", "34", "45"}, ___ ~~ {"1", "4"} ~~ ___]
```

> {True, False, True, True}

Why does this work? Why are we able to specify the different possibilities with a list instead of with Alternatives?.

I have also found out we do not even need to evaluate Alternatives properly, the following does work as well:

```
 StringMatchQ[{"12", "23", "34", "45"}, ___ ~~ Alternatives @ {"1", "4"} ~~ ___]
```

> {True, False, True, True}

even though the head of `List` is not replaced:

```
Alternatives@{"1", "4"}
```

what yields the (undefined?) symbolic expression:

> Alternatives[{"1", "4"}]

Why these last two ways work and where is it documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `FullForm` of the pattern; you will notice that it becomes a `StringExpression`:

```
FullForm[___ ~~ {"1", "4"} ~~ ___]

(* Out: StringExpression[BlankNullSequence[], List["1", "4"], BlankNullSequence[]] *)
```

The second bullet point in the "Details" section of the [documentation of `StringExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringExpression.html) lists the types of objects that can appear in `StringExpression`, among which is

"{$p_1$, $p_2$, ...} or $p_1$ | $p_2$ |...      ->      a pattern matching at least one of the $p_i$".

For your second question, I interpret `Alternatives[{"1", "4"}]` to mean "a pattern object that represents any of the patterns `{"1", "4"}`", which I would then interpret as the pattern `{"1", "4"}` itself. Then you go back to what we discussed above.